# Python - Tips on Rewrite of BeautifulSoup function to be more elegant

Tags: python, if-statement, beautifulsoup, conditional-operator

The code is working but I am looking for tips on how this could be written a little more properly, especially the use of if's. As you can tell I am not a programmer by nature... just a sys admin doing a little fiddling in python. Thanks for any advice you can provide.

```python
def findallWileyLinks():

pagebase = 'http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com'
journallist = 'http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/browse/publications?type=journal&&start=0&resultsPerPage=3000'

inputList = getinputList()

if inputList:
  alljournallistsoup = BeautifulSoup(getwebpage(journallist))

  if alljournallistsoup:
    alljournallisttags = alljournallistsoup.find('ol', attrs={'id' : 'publications'})

    for eissn in inputList:
      journalatag = alljournallisttags.find('a', attrs={'href' : re.compile(eissn.rstrip() + '$')})

      if journalatag:
        journalsoup = BeautifulSoup(getwebpage(pagebase + journalatag.get('href') + '/issues'))

        if journalsoup:
          allvolumetags = journalsoup.find('ol', attrs={'class' : 'issueVolumes'})
          volumeatags = allvolumetags.findAll('a')

            for volumeatag in volumeatags:
              volumesoup = BeautifulSoup(getwebpage(pagebase + volumeatag.get('href')))

              if volumesoup:
                allissuetags = volumesoup.find('li', attrs={'id' : volumeatag.get('id')[:-5]})
                issueatags = allissuetags.findAll('a')[1:]

                  for issueatag in issueatags:
                    currentlinksavailiable.append(pagebase + issueatag.get('href') + '\n')

      else:
        appendlog('eISSN: ' + eissn.rstrip() + ' not found on alljournallist page.')

    try:
      with open(inputDirectory + selectedPublisher + '_currentlinksavailiable.txt', 'w') as f:
          f.writelines(currentlinksavailiable)

    except IOError as e:
      appendlog('findallLinks() Operation failed probably when creating the new link text file with error: %s' % e.strerror)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that jumps out at me is that you have a lot of code of the form:

```
tags = parenttag.findAll('tag')

if tags:
    for tag in tags:
        # do something to tag
```

You are guaranteed that `tags` is a list here, so the `if tags:` line is redundant. If you use an empty list in a `for` loop then the body of the loop is not executed.

As a small point, at the beginning of the file `inputList = []` can be removed as you immediately overwrite it with the function call.

It's not clear if this is part of a larger script or not, but if it isn't then rather than including the body of the script in an `if` block you should terminate if `inputList` is empty.

```
if not inputList:
    sys.exit(1)
```

rather than

```
if inputList:
    # process inputList
```

You'll need to add `import sys` to the top of your script for that to work.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The if's before a for have been removed along with the inputList = [] and currentlinksavailiable = []. this is part of a larger script. This is written to fetch links for a particular publisher. Once this is refined, I will use it as a template to write more similar functions for other publishers.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the code in a function and make most of your if statements negative and use return, continue or break statements.  That would avoid so much indentation.

Also, there's an if statement right before a for loop that looks like it's not needed, since if the list is empty, then the for loop gets skipped. 
I.e.

```
if volumeatags:
    for volumeatag in volumeatags:
            ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment about not needing the if before a for. That makes sense and removed a few unneeded lines. I will read up on the use of return/continue/break statements because i would definately like to minimize indentation. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of this code is unnecessary. Some examples:

```
inputList = []
inputList = getinputList()
```

In Python, you do not need to initialize variables before assigning data to them. The second line would be fine on its own.

```
if volumeatags:
   for volumeatag in volumeatags:
```

If `volumeatags` is empty, the for loop won't execute.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is very common to ask for rewrites here. Anyway, here is my feedback.

```
if foo:
    if bar:
        #code
```

Replace with (asusming you are inside a `def`, but you are, right?

```
if not foo:
    return
if bar:
    #code
```

Comments should start with hash-blank-uppercase, keep hash-lowercase for code you have commented out. Peter Norvig seems to put two dashes in textual comments. Anyway you have too many comments.  Code should be descriptive enough. If a block of operations needs a descritive header, move it in a function and use this description as the function name. It will help also to isolate things.

Don't guard your `for foo` loops with `if foo`, as noted in other answers.

`inputList = []` is useless, and not PEP08 compliant, try `input`.

Comment: Even better would be `if foo and bar` -- fewer lines is often better than more :-)

Comment: Thanks, I will strip the comments from my origional posting here for easier readability. I am a sys admin so programming isnt necessarily my strong point and hench a bunch of comments.